# TestCafe/Atom Run Results after computer restart

Tags: javascript, node.js, console, atom-editor, testcafe

I have a large number of tests that I kicked off and ran last night before leaving work. I left them running over night. Our testing platform is TestCafe/Atom/Node.JS. We do not yet have a reporting system in place so whatever runs, the results are reported in the console window as pass-fail.

Apparently my computer decided to do some kind of auto update and restart. So when I came into the the office there was no console and no instance of Atom running. Which means I cannot see my test results from last night.

Is there any way for me to find these test results without a reporting system in place? Or do I just need to consider this last over-night test run results as a total loss?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, your test results are gone, because Atom doesn't save contents of console window to a log file automatically.

But you can prevent such situations in future by explicitly writing test results to a file. You can easily create a copy of a test report with TestCafe using [multiple reporters](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/command-line-interface.html#-r-namefile---reporter-namefile) feature:

`testcafe all tests/sample-fixture.js -r spec,xunit:report.xml`

By executing this command, you will get test results in the console window, and in the `report.xml` file.

Comment: Thank you! Yes I have since started using this -r spec,xunit:report.xml. :-D